# Listas usando iterador java

Tags: java, lista, clase, nodos, iteradores

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio de java trata de sacar en una lista solo las asignaturas aprobadas de un alumno, yo habia pensado en:

```
public Lista Aprobadas{
  Lista final= new Lista();
  Iterador it=expediente.getIterador();
  while(it.hasNext)){
     if(it.next().getNota()>=5)
         final.insertar(it.next());
     }
   return final;
}
```

El problema es q al hacer eso y meter por ejemplo las notas: 4, 2, 7, 6 solo saca el 6, entinedo que es por it.next() del insertar pero no se como hacerlo de otra forma.
También había pensado pasando a la lista final todas las notas e ir borrando todas aquellas que sean menos de 5 pero tampoco funciona:

```
public Lista Aprobadas{
  Lista final= new Lista();
  final=expediente;
  Iterador it=expediente.getIterador();
  Evaluar prueba=new Evaluar (it.next().getAsignatura(),it.next().getFecha(),it.next().getNota());
  while(it.hasNext)){
     if(prueba.getNota()>=5){
         final.insertar(prueba);}
     prueba=it.next();
     }

   return final;
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada vez que usas

```
it.next()
```

pasas al siguiente valor del iterador.

Entonces, cuando te entra el 7, lo compruebas, pero a la hora de meterlo a la lista, haces

```
final.insertar(it.next());
```

Es decir, le insertas el 6.

En

```
Evaluar prueba=new Evaluar (it.next().getAsignatura(),it.next().getFecha(),it.next().getNota());
```

Le estás pasando la asignatura del elemento siguiente al actual, la fecha del siguiente y la nota del siguiente.

Mi consejo es que en cada iteración ejecutes solamente una vez .next() y lo guardes en un objeto, así podrás acceder a las variables de ese objeto. Así:

```
public Lista Aprobadas{
  Lista final= new Lista();
  Iterador it=expediente.getIterador();
  while(it.hasNext)){
     Nota n = it.next();
     if(n.getNota()>=5)
         final.insertar(n);
     }
   return final;
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Funciona sin errores. Te lo agradezco mucho :)

Comment: Me alegro! De nada! Confirma que la duda fue resuelta.